# What makes explorer.exe unable to start?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

I install an update yesterday and now `explorer.exe` is unable to start. I can still access Task Manager, and from there I can open other programs. However `explorer.exe` doesn't start, nor yield any error. Running `ms-settings:display` yields this error:

[image]

Other things that doesn't help:

| Command | What happens |
| --- | --- |
| `sfc /scannow` | Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations. |
| `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot network` | Booting to safemode success, but it still fails to run `explorer.exe` |
| `chkdsk` | Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems. |
| `Get-ComputerRestorePoint` | Nothing returns |
| `eventvwr` or `devmgmt.msc` | I don't know what to look for |

Here are the list of recent updates:

```
wmic qfe list
Caption                                     CSName       Description      FixComments  HotFixID   InstallDate  InstalledBy          InstalledOn  Name  ServicePackInEffect  Status
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=5029921  OOKERLAPTOP  Update                        KB5029921               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2023
https://support.microsoft.com/help/5012170  OOKERLAPTOP  Security Update               KB5012170               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  12/7/2022
https://support.microsoft.com/help/5030310  OOKERLAPTOP  Update                        KB5030310               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/27/2023
                                            OOKERLAPTOP  Update                        KB5028756               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/26/2023
                                            OOKERLAPTOP  Update                        KB5030508               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/27/2023
```

According to `winver`, I'm using Windows 11 Home 22H2 (22621.2361).

Comment: Have you tried safe mode yet?  Inspect eventvwr for any clues.  Process monitor might shed some light as well.  If you just need to get up and running, try using System Restore to roll back before the 9/27 hotfixes were installed.  If that doesn't work, you could try booting to WinPE and removing the hotfixes that way, and while you're in WinPE, try runnig "sfc /scannow" and chkdsk.  Is there anything sticking out in devicemgr?

Comment: All of them don't fix the problem (except booting to WinPE as I haven't tried yet). I update the question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[KB5030310](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/september-26-2023-kb5030310-os-build-22621-2361-preview-363ac1ae-6ea8-41b3-b3cc-22a2a5682faf)
is a Preview, meaning that it is being tested and in the future,
when fully tested and debugged, the finished update will be
released under another number.

It is not recommended to start Windows Update and execute all the
suggested updates, since you then expose yourself to the installation
of unfinished updates that are still in beta test.
It is much safer to wait for Windows to announce that an update is
available, as Preview updates are never installed automatically,
only manually by yourself running Windows Update.

I can't state that KB5030310 is the root of the problem, but I suggest
to uninstall it, reboot and see if this solves the problem.
If needed, uninstall the other updates that were installed
just before this problem arrived. Uninstall one-by-one and
reboot after each one, in order to identify the problematic
update.

To uninstall updates :

- Run *Settings > Update & Security > View update history >
  Uninstall updates*.
  Alternatively, run
  *Control Panel > Programs and Features > View installed updates*.
- Right-click an update, select "Uninstall" and follow the prompts.

Comment: running `wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:5030310` fixes the problem. Any chance you know why would this update affect `explorer.exe`?

Comment: Anything can happen when installing a Windows update that was not fully tested.

Comment: FYI - installed that update on two systems today without issue - apparently this issue occurs if tabs in explorer are disabled

Comment: I suggest to signal this problem to Microsoft via the the Feedback Hub.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my Windows 10 Dell laptop. Explorer.exe would not start. Subsequently, I would log into a black screen with a cursor.

After logging in and getting the black screen, do -Ctrl-Alt-Del and select Task Manager...File.....Run New Task.....Type explorer.exe and hit OK.
If this doesn't give you your Desktop, then go to the following in the registry. Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon Use regedit.exe. You'll have to use Task Manager to launch it. Paste this path at the top of the program or click down to the Winlogin subkey. Once there, click the key and in the right pane,
double click the Shell value and type explorer.exe for the value data. Close and reboot. If you still cannot boot into your desktop, then check the Userinit value under the same subkey, Winlogon.
Using Task Manager again, use regedit and go back to the Winlogon folder. In the right pane, double click the Userinit value and type C:\WINDOWS\System32\userinit.exe for the value data. Close and reboot. Hopefully, you'll get your desktop after logging in. I believe userinit.exe is what starts the explorer.exe shell in Windows, giving you the desktop. Sometimes, programs or updates change it, causing the desktop not to load when Windows boots. Using the native Windows userinit.exe program might solve the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).